# Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers on Vagrant

Tags: linux, virtualbox, vagrant, wget

Trying to install aaPanel into a vagrant machine. vagrant box used is Scotch box 3.5 which preloaded with php v7.0. I've updated php to v7.4 using sury's ppa and working fine.

I've used given instruction on [here](https://forum.aapanel.com/d/9-aapanel-linux-panel-684-installation-tutorial/111), and used Ubuntu specific commands as given.

```
buntu/Deepin :

    wget -O install.sh http://www.aapanel.com/script/install-ubuntu_6.0_en.sh && sudo bash install.sh
```

command didn't ran correctly at first, then I tried `wget` with User agent added.

```
sudo wget -l1 -U "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux i686 (x86_64)) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/55.0.2883.75 Safari/537.36"  -O install.sh http://www.aapanel.com/script/install-ubuntu_6.0_en.sh && sudo bash install.sh
```

then it *kinda* worked but in the middle, I got another issue. (actually same error message)

```
(try: 6)  http://download.bt.cn/src/Python-3.7.8.tar.xz
Connecting to download.bt.cn (download.bt.cn)|103.224.251.67|:80... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
Retrying.
```

the error

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... Read error (Connection reset by peer) in headers.
    Retrying.
```

was there before I add the user agent. so I thought adding user agent to `wget` in install.sh file would fix that and sadly it didn't.

This is the final error message

```
ERROR: Download python source code fielded.
Ubuntu 16.04.2 LTS
 \l
Bit:64 Mem:992M Core:1
Linux scotchbox 4.4.0-75-generic #96-Ubuntu SMP Thu Apr 20 09:56:33 UTC 2017 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

how can I fix this?